# How to code "Set image size = Clicks+100"?

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, click

I know how to do this on my calculator, in qbasic, and in a video game called Trials. How do I set the size of a picture, which is also a hyperlink, to be equal to an equation involving the amount of times the hyperlink has been clicked on in a day or other time period?

I am trying to achieve what I often see on forums where the most searched terms or tags are in a 32 or 48 point font whereas the least amount are closer to 10 or 12 point font, but using an image.

I have not used any web code other than HTML so far, so what would you recommend to be the simplest code to begin with for my website? I just need basic if-then statements, and storing and calling variables and strings.

I thank you at the very least for reading this post.

Comment: Please remove the tag _java_ as this seems to be a _javascript_ question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Probably you need to learn Javascript or find a good framework like Bootstrap that may have what you need. Otherwise, on this site generally is best to post some code you have tried and people will help to find problems.